# How to grep on files less than a size and limit to extension

Tags: grep, find, pipe, gnu

I want to recursively grep on all files in subdirectories with extension `csv` but select only those files that are less than 4M in size. Is this correct way to do?

```
find . -type f -size -4M | grep --include \*.csv 'pattern'
```

This command selects all the files with `.csv`, basically doesn't limit to less than 4M in size, although `find` alone correctly finds all files less than 4M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll set up some fake data:

```
$ for fileno in {1..4}; do for line in {1..100000}; do printf "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM; done > ~/tmp/big-fake-${fileno}.csv; done
$ for fileno in {1..4}; do for line in {1..50000}; do printf "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM; done > ~/tmp/small-fake-$fileno.csv; done
```

Let's verify it has the properties you're interested in:

```
$ du -b tmp/*.csv
4528666 tmp/big-fake-1.csv
4529227 tmp/big-fake-2.csv
4529173 tmp/big-fake-3.csv
4528782 tmp/big-fake-4.csv
2263714 tmp/small-fake-1.csv
2264028 tmp/small-fake-2.csv
2264398 tmp/small-fake-3.csv
2265134 tmp/small-fake-4.csv
```

Now let's look for some kind of pattern in the smaller files:

```
$ find tmp/ -type f -iregex ".*\.csv" -size -4M -exec grep '1,1,1' {} +
tmp/small-fake-3.csv:15361,2526,13438,1083,3224,13221,1,19248
```

Naturally the `grep` here can take other flags, eg `-l` if you're only interested in the filenames which contain the pattern you want.

The `{} +` you can think of as kind of a template for "insert a list of filenames discovered by `find` in place of the brackets." Since Grep is happy to take a list of filenames rather than one at a time, this is superior to `-exec grep '1,1,1' {} \;`, which would launch a new instance of Grep for every separate file, one at a time.

This `-exec` flag I believe is a GNU-ism and not available in other types of `find`. I think on other platforms they go with a `find -print0 | xargs -0` type of pattern. (I'm sure someone will leave a comment elaborating on this.)

Comment: No, `print0` and similar is non-portable. `-exec` exists since `find` exists on UNIX. The problem with GNU find is that it ignored newer features (until I asked them to implement it...) of the real find and e.g. did not implement support for the `-exec +` that was added 1988.That non-portable `xarags` toy was introduced by GNU find instead of looking for good ideas like execplus from David Korn from 1988.

Comment: @ewr3243 using `-type f`

Comment: I'll edit the answer, although I don't think it would affect anything because directories won't be matching `-iregex ".*\.csv"`

Comment: @shily Thanks for insight!

Comment: I used your answer and modified with `-name "*.csv"`. How different is that from your version?

Comment: @ewr3243 Should work the same. I usually just go with the regex flags instead of name because it's more flexible.

Comment: `-exec` is in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), it's not limited to GNU find